# How to remove unwanted space of jface widget which is disposing dynamically

Tags: java, layout, swt, jface

I am designing a GUI in jface/swt,in which I am creating a scrolledform which contains a section and inside that section there is a composite.
On that composite,i am adding a comboviewer which has 2 elements.
on selecting first element, there are 2 widgets, one is label with textbox and other is table.
On selecting second element, there is only one widget that is label with textbox.
Now,my problem is that when i am selecting second element it is disposing the table but the space occupied by table is remain there.

so,how to remove that unwanted space after selecting seconnd element.
Please help me out.

Here is my first function in which i am creating scrolled form

```
 class Test extends FormDialog{
        protected void createFormContent(IManagedForm managedform) {
            toolkit = managedform.getToolkit();
            scrolledForm = managedform.getForm();
            Shell shell = scrolledForm.getShell();
            shell.setText("First Form");

        // I am using GridLayout and GridData.

        scrolledForm.pack();
        scrolledForm.reflow(true);
    }

// After this there is a method containing section and a composite inside the section.

    protected void createCombo(final Composite client) {    
        Label label1 = toolkit.createLabel(client,"First Label : ", SWT.NULL);

        final ComboViewer comboViewer1 = new ComboViewer(client,SWT.NORMAL|SWT.NORMAL);

    //In this Compoviewer1, I am adding 2 persons ie "ABC"  and "XYZ".

        comboViewer1.getCombo().select(0);

    // Here I am Calling Two methods, createFirstContent() method contains label and comboviewer. And createSecondContent() method contains TableViewer which is created inside a Group
        createFirstContent(client);     
        createSecondContent(client);


        comboViewer1.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener(){

            @Override
            public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
                IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) event
                        .getSelection();

                if(((Person) selection.getFirstElement()).getName().equals("ABC")){

                    createFirstContent(client);     
                    createSecondContent(client);

                }else if(((Person) selection.getFirstElement()).getName().equals("XYZ")){
                    if(tablegroup != null && !(tablegroup.isDisposed())){
                        tablegroup.dispose();

                        createFirstContent(client); 
                    }
                }); 
    }

    protected void createFirstContent(Composite clientComposite){

    Label label = toolkit.createLabel(clientComposite,"First Lbl : ", SWT.NULL);
    label .setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL,true, false));

    ComboViewer combo = new ComboViewer(clientComposite, SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.NORMAL);   

    }

    protected void createSecondContent(Composite clientComposite) {

            tablegroup = new Group(clientComposite, SWT.FILL);
            tablegroup.setLayout(new GridLayout());
            tablegroup.setText("Table Group");


            createTableViewer(tablegroup);
            GridData gridData = new GridData();
            gridData.verticalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
            gridData.horizontalSpan = 2;
            gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = false;
            gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
            gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
            tablegroup.setLayoutData(gridData);


    }

    protected void createTableViewer(Group tablegroup) {
        viewer = new TableViewer(tablegroup, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);

        TableColumnLayout tcl = new TableColumnLayout();
        createColumns(tcl);

        final Table table = viewer.getTable();
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLinesVisible(true);

        GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL,true, true;     
        gridData.horizontalSpan = 2;

        viewer.getControl().setLayoutData(gridData);

    }
```

In the createColums() method, i am creating the columns of table.

After all these things, i am creating another section.and creating some other widgets in that section.

but my problem is that when i am disposing taht table while selecting XYZ, table will get disposed but the space occupied by table is not removing.
So, there will be an unwanted gap/space between both the sections. 
Please tell me how to remove that space.

Comment: sample code might help

Comment: It depends on the Layout that you are using so you need to show us some code.